# featherjs app hoooks vs service hooks documentation unclear

Tags: feathersjs, feather

Do app level hooks have any methods for registration? because as in featherjs [documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/basic-feathers/all-about-hooks.html)

It cites

```
`app.hooks({
before: {
create: hook30a()
},after: {
create: hook39a()
},
});`
```

where do this create method comes in app? Its all registered as service methods right at some path?

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are not in the `app`. It means that those hooks will run for every service. As documented in the [application hook API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#application-hooks):

> To add hooks to every service app.hooks(hooks) can be used. Application hooks are registered in the same format as service hooks and also work exactly the same.